# Kendo UI Window Opens after two clicks in IE 8

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I have a kendoUI window that I am trying to open, the code works fine in Firefox however in order for it to open in IE8 I need to click the button twice. I can't for the life of me figure out why this is.

Here is the code for the button (HTML):

```
<div id="CCA_UserAdministration_NewUserRequest">
    Content of the Window
</div>
<div id="CCA_UserAdministration_UserRequestBtn" onclick="javascript:CCA.UserAdministration.OpenUserRequestWindow();" class="k-button">New User Request</div>
```

(JS):

```
CCA.UserAdministration.OpenUserRequestWindow = function () {

        CCA.UserAdministration.UserRequestWin = $("#CCA_UserAdministration_NewUserRequest").kendoWindow({
            height: "200px",
            title: "New User Request Form",
            visible: false,

            width: "500px"
        }).data("kendoWindow");
        $('#CCA_UserAdministration_NewUserRequest').show();
     CCA.UserAdministration.UserRequestWin.center().open();     
};
```

I have a namespace defined earlier in the JS File:

```
var CCA = CCA || {};
CCA.UserAdministration = CCA.UserAdministration || {};
```

**Edit**

I should also mention that on the initial first click this image is hidden in IE8. No idea why.

```
<img src="/_layouts/images/fgimg.png" alt="" style="left:-0px !important;top:-128px !important;position:absolute;">
```

Also, if I turn modal = true, it will not allow me to click the second time as the dark screen comes up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to the jquery version jQuery 1.8.+. You can resolve this by using  jQuery 1.7.# or by disabling the animation of the window using animation:false.

```
CCA.UserAdministration.OpenUserRequestWindow = function () {

    CCA.UserAdministration.UserRequestWin = $("#CCA_UserAdministration_NewUserRequest").kendoWindow({
        height: "200px",
        title: "New User Request Form",
        visible: false,
        animation: false,
        width: "500px"
    }).data("kendoWindow");
    $('#CCA_UserAdministration_NewUserRequest').show();
 CCA.UserAdministration.UserRequestWin.center().open();   };
```

Comment: The current release of Kendo UI fixes many bugs related to jQuery 1.8+, maybe you should also check your Kendo UI Version (currently, 2012.3.1114 from November 2012)

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to replace the CCA_UserAdministration_UserRequestBtn DIV and make it an anchor:

```
<a id="CCA_UserAdministration_UserRequestBtn" href="javascript:CCA.UserAdministration.OpenUserRequestWindow();" class="k-button">New User Request</a>
```

IE could have difficulties with a syntax like:
 `onclick="javascript:CCA.UserAdministration.OpenUserRequestWindow();"`, usually you dont have the `javascript:` part in the `onclick` handler, so you might also want to just make it `onclick="CCA.UserAdministration.OpenUserRequestWindow()"`. When using the `href` attribute though, you need the `javascript:` part.

Comment: unfortunately this didn't fix it.